# Is there an integration solution to integrate OWASP ZAP and Testlink with each other?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework, testlink, zapproxy

**Starting point:**
We are currently using OWASP Zap for our security test within a CI/CD pipeline based on Docker.

At the same time, we have Python based test cases that we execute within an API based test procedure.To find vulnerabilities in APIs.

We also use Testlink as a test management solution. But what we don't have is a direct integration with Owasp Zap to work at test management level, and use the run test accordingly in a management level.

**Question:**
Is there an integration possibility of Owasp Zap with Testlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, lots of security testing services provider are available in the market.Qwasp Zap currently doesn't provide the integration with Testlink.
Further, it provide integration for other testing tools.
Please refer below link to check the tools supported by it.

https://spiradoc.inflectra.com/RemoteLaunch-User-Guide/ZAPTEST/